# iOS: understanding global variables

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, variables, global-variables

In my first `ViewController` `ViewControllerTest1` I've got a global variable called `counter`.
`counter` is supposed to be increased every now and then in my app. Everything works fine:

```
@implementation ViewControllerTest1{
int counter = 0;

-(void)viewDidLoad
{...}

-(void)method {...}
}
```

Now if I declare another global variable called `counter` in my second `ViewController` `ViewControllerTest2` XCode gives me an error.

I know I can just give it a different name, but why does that happen? Can I make sure only the globals of the certain `ViewController` that is active are in my memory?

Or am I doing something like a no go right now with globals like `counter`? 
Is there something better?

Comment: if you want interface specific global variable then make it member in same interface...declare inside interface in .h file

Comment: The code you posted isn't valid. The curly braces are wrong. Please fix them because if the close curly really belongs just after `int counter` then you don't have a global, you have a private instance variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a symbol to be specific to a file, use the `static` keyword when declaring it.

Your declaration should look like

```
static int counter = 0;
```

At link time (after all the files were compiled), the global symbols are mixed up in the same file, and therefore, if two share the same name, an error is fired by the linker.

Comment: The symbol conflict happens during linking.  If two files both declare the same symbol, a duplicate symbol conflict occurs.  Another way to fix this is to mark one declaration as `extern` (which would typically be done in the header that corresponds to the implementation file the declares the actual global).

Comment: @bbum You commented while i was answering. Does this version of my answer seems right to you ? I didn't want to mention `extern` in it because there were no use in the op case.

Comment: @TomAhh You still state the error comes from the compiler. It's the linker that complains about the duplicate symbols.

Comment: Yup -- upvoted, too, while changing my comment to indicate an alternative solution if the variable is supposed to be truly global.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a variable at file scope (which includes locations within a class definition but outside the ivar area or a method body), it will have `extern` linkage by default, which requires unique symbol names.

Make it a `static` variable (`static int ...`) and the problem will be resolved, because static symbol names only need to be unique within the file in which they are declared.

If you are accessing this variable *outside* this file intentionally, and so need to maintain `extern` linkage, you will need to name the other variable something else to distinguish the two.